# Placing text and slideshow side-by-side in a box

Tags: css, html, slideshow, box

I'm trying to place a slideshow side-by-side of text, with the slideshow to the right, and contain it all within a box.  I thought I got it right at first, by simply containing it in a table with text in one column and the slideshow in the other, but as soon as I finished coding the slideshow, it refuses to stay within the parameters of the box - I've tried using section, aside, article, or the basic div elements as well and I just can't get it to work.

This is my html:

```
<table class="main">
<tr>
<th>
...random text here...
</th>
<td>

<div class="slideshow">
<figure>
    <img src="Pics/slide show/1.jpg" style="width:500px;height:500px;" />
</figure>
<figure>
    <img src="Pics/slide show/2.jpg" style="width:500px;height:500px;" />
</figure>
<figure>
    <img src="Pics/slide show/3.gif" style="width:500px;height:500px;" />
</figure>
<figure>
    <img src="Pics/slide show/4.jpg" style="width:500px;height:500px;" />
</figure>
<figure>
    <img src="Pics/slide show/5.jpg" style="width:500px;height:500px;" />
</figure>
<figure>
    <img src="Pics/slide show/6.jpg" style="width:500px;height:500px;" />
</figure>
<figure>
    <img src="Pics/slide show/7.jpg" style="width:500px;height:500px;" />
</figure>
<figure>
    <img src="Pics/slide show/8.jpg" style="width:500px;height:500px;" />
</figure>
<figure>
    <img src="Pics/slide show/9.jpg" style="width:500px;height:500px;" />
</figure>
<figure>
    <img src="Pics/slide show/10.jpg" style="width:500px;height:500px;" />
</figure>
<figure>
    <img src="Pics/slide show/11.png" style="width:500px;height:500px;" />
</figure>
<figure>
    <img src="Pics/slide show/12.jpg" style="width:500px;height:500px;" />
</figure>
<figure>
    <img src="Pics/slide show/13.jpg" style="width:500px;height:500px;" />
</figure>
<figure>
    <img src="Pics/slide show/14.png" style="width:500px;height:500px;" />
</figure>
</div>

</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

And this is my css:

```
table.main {
background-color:#fff;
margin:20px;
padding:20px;
border:5px solid black;
text-align:center;
font-family:"Fredericka the Great";
display:div;
}

table.main th, td {
padding:20px;
margin:20px;
}

table.main th {
padding:40px;
margin:50px;
font-size:25px;
}
.slideshow{
position:relative;
max-width:500px;
height:500px;
}
.slideshow figure{
margin:0;
position:absolute;
opacity:0;
}
figure:nth-child(1){
animation: xfade 42s 39s infinite;
}
figure:nth-child(2){
animation: xfade 78s 72s infinite;
}
figure:nth-child(3){
animation: xfade 78s 66s infinite;
}
figure:nth-child(4){
animation: xfade 78s 60s infinite;
}
figure:nth-child(5){
animation: xfade 78s 54s infinite;
}
figure:nth-child(6){
animation: xfade 78s 48s infinite;
}
figure:nth-child(7){
animation: xfade 78s 42s infinite;
}
figure:nth-child(8){
animation: xfade 78s 36s infinite;
}
figure:nth-child(9){
animation: xfade 78s 30s infinite;
}
figure:nth-child(10){
animation: xfade 78s 24s infinite;
}
figure:nth-child(11){
animation: xfade 78s 18s infinite;
}
figure:nth-child(12){
animation: xfade 78s 12s infinite;
}
figure:nth-child(13){
animation: xfade 78s 6s infinite;
}
figure:nth-child(14){
animation: xfade 78s 0s infinite;
}
@keyframes xfade{
0%{
    opacity:1;
}
4.5%{
    opacity:1;
}
7.15%{
    opacity:0;
}
95%{
    opacity:0;
}
100%{
    opacity:1;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/8734jsxL/

Since `.slideshow figure` is positioned  `absolute`, it is taken out of the flow of the layout, so the `.slideshow` calculates its width without taken into account the figure. You could just specify `width: 500px` to make sure it stays wide enough.

Also, I couldn't really understand what you were trying to do with your CSS animation code and just made all the figures opaque. However, this is very efficient code for making a slideshow. I hope this is just an exercise in demonstrating the extreme uses of CSS, and that you know a javascript solution would be much simpler and more extensible.